# Ошибка при создании списка команд

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

ошибка:

```
Uncaught TelegramError Error: 400: Bad Request: BOT_COMMAND_INVALID
    at TelegramError (c:\Users\Maxim\node_modules\telegraf\lib\core\network\error.js:6:9)
    at callApi (c:\Users\Maxim\node_modules\telegraf\lib\core\network\client.js:264:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
telegraf.js 4.7.0
```

```
tg.telegram.setMyCommands([
  {command: "/Перевод", description:"[сумма] [айди человека которому отправляете] - переводит сумму человеку"},
  {command: "/Баланс", description:"отображает ваш баланс"}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Возникла такая ошибка, когда в тексте команды использовал заглавные буквы.
Как только заглавные буквы убрал, ошибка исчезла

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).